# Does Persona 5 Royal have all of Persona 5's DLC?

Tags: persona-5, persona-5-royal

I got *Persona 5 Royal* the other day. It occurred to me however that unlike Persona 3 and 4 that got expanded versions later on (Persona 3 had FES and Portable and Persona 4 had Golden) neither had DLC for it and unlike generally I would expect all the DLC to be self contained in a Game of the year Edition (ie. Borderlands, The Witcher 3) and I wouldn't call these Game of the Year Editions.

So does *Persona 5 Royal* have all of *Persona 5*'s DLC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persona 5 Royal does not come with the original Persona 5 DLC automatically installed, but you are able to download the [Legacy DLC Bundle](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP0177-CUSA17416_00-P5RDLCBUNDLE0001) free of charge

> The 'Persona®5 Royal Legacy DLC Bundle' comes with all the additional content from the original Persona®5.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gamespot.com/articles/psa-persona-5-royal-players-get-all-persona-5-dlc-/1100-6475449/

It looks like it comes with all DLC included.